# Обратится к элементу в XAML разметке? - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть StackPanel

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel
        {
            Width = MainGrid.ActualWidth,
            Height = MainGrid.ActualWidth,
            Name="StackPanel1"

        };
```

Как обратиться к этому экземпляру в XAML разметке?

Comment: Где этот объект у вас создается?

Comment: В смысле?  В  Window_Loaded   Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

Comment: Если вы создаете этот объект в `Window_Loaded` и нигде больше на него не ссылаетесь, после того как обработчик отработает, ссылка на объект `StackPanel` будет потеряна. Если не секрет зачем такой костыль - создать в `code behind`, а обратиться в `XAML`?

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.Children.Add(sp );
```

Имя `Name="grid"` должно быть в XAML

Comment: У меня в окне Grid , а StackPanel я создаю специально размерами равными Grid но как бы "поверх него"

Comment: Ну добавлю я StackPanel в Grid, а как мне  потом к нему обратится?

Comment: у тебя же уже есть sp и grid - через них и обращайся

Comment: Отредактируйте пожалуйста ответ, добавив  в него XAML разметку  - КАК мне на grid обратится к stackPanel? Заранее спасибо.